# Find the Taylor polynomial of degree $3$ of $f(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)$, centered at $x_0=0$

Tags: proof-verification, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the Taylor polynomial of degree $3$ of $f(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)$, centered at $x_0=0$. My answer is in the picture below. Are these steps correct?

[Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URcxt.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: It looks correct.  Note that $f^{(n+2)}(x)=f^{(n)}(x)$

Comment: $$1-x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4)$$